# Reactive programming in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, reactive-programming

I saw that Vue.js has officially supported `vue-rx` package but the number of monthly downloads is really small. Does it mean that `vuex` is covering most of the needs and the whole Vue architecture is steering you in that direction?

Is reactive development recommended in Vue.js (using RxJS, Most, Bacon or something else) and if so which external tool is most commonly used?

Comment: It seems to me that Vue itself is sufficiently reactive that there's little benefit in tacking on another package that does much the same thing in a different way.

Comment: I'd agree with Roy. In RxJS data starts from observables and "bubbles" through their APIs. In Vue.js data starts from simple events or http requests, and "bubbles" through computed properties and Vuex getters. You could use RxJS in a Vue.js application but I'd say you won't have any benefit from it.

Comment: Although `vue-rx` is not as common, I see there are examples where using the rxjs simplifies your code over vuex. You can find my talk on this topic at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1rckjbSN08